# nodejs with expressjs and SSL p7b certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https, p7b

I'm very sorry for my language but I'm not speak english.

I'm trying to implement in my app SSL but I have only valud p7b created by csr file. I'm using expressjs and node js on linux server. I know how to implement PEM certificate

```
var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./private.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./' + config.ssl[config.mode].cert)
    };

    server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000);
```

but I don't know how implement p7b certificate, kindly help me

Comment: did you ever get your answer?  I am running into the same issue...

Comment: do you ever find any solution ?

Comment: Slightly off topic here. If there's no solution, how about implementing SSL on the server networking settings? Like on ubuntu with apache2 + lets encrypt SSL cert (free).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to conver your p7b to pem format:

```
openssl pkcs7 -in public.p7b -inform DER -out public.pem -print_certs
```

Create a pkcs12 file contiaing your private key and the public certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private.key -in public.pem -name my_name -out result.pfx
```

To use the pfx file with node js use

```
const cert = fs.readFileSync("result.pfx");
const request = require('request').defaults({
    agentOptions: {
        pfx: cert,
        passphrase: password
    }
});
```